# Can arangodb handle 20 billion records?

Tags: arangodb, arangodb-php

I just want to know, can Arangodb handle 20 billions of records in a single collection?

What is the best way to insert 1 billion records at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Of course. The underlying storage engine choice should definitely be RocksDB. How big would every individual document in average be?

The best way would be any sort of import/restore. Is this going to be a cluster or a single server deployment?

Comment: The individual document can be of size 1 kb. Currently I am using it as a single server and mmfiles as a storage engine.

Comment: MMFiles is not an option unless you are looking into buying 20 exabyte of RAM. Memory mapped files performance goes towards zero, when data size including indexes cannot be matched in RAM size.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You suggested the best way to insert records is import/restore, but to use that my whole data should be ready before insertion,right? Suppose my data is generated at run time using some sort of script, at that time what should I use?

Comment: Absolutely. By all means insert all you data.